# Can "get" be used as a linking verb in a context of a gradual change?

Tags: linking-verbs

Can "get" be used as a linking verb in a context of a gradual change?

For instance, instead of saying:

> She came/grew to like him more.

Can I say:

> She got to like him more.

Comment: It's certainly a usage I have heard, but I wouldn't use it myself. I would call it colloquial - and it seems to me to be American (though that may not be reliable).

Comment: American here.  This is used, but not to indicate gradual change.  You would use "got" to indicate something obtained or a change in state.  "She got her coat." or "She got tired."  But it's in the past, so it has already happened.  You could say, "She began to get to like him," but it is still rather verbose way of simply saying "She came/grew to like him."

Comment: @Neil This is a good comment, but it would be an even better answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly in usage in southern England where I live, and without performing extensive investigations, I'll point you towards the lyrics for the Rogers and Hammerstein musical "The King and I" and the song "Getting to Know You"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MNANgFCYpk

Contextually the King and Anna have spent a good deal of time together and during that time:

> It's a very ancient saying
>   But a true and honest thought That if you
>   become a teacher By your pupils you'll be taught As a teacher I've
>   been learning You'll forgive me if I boast And I've now become an
>   expert On the subject I like most
>
> Getting to know you.
>   Getting to know you. Getting to know all about you. 
>   Getting to like you.  Getting to hope you like me.

If you'll pardon me, I'm just ***getting used to formatting*** my posts.
(As in "growing accustomed to doing it over some period of time").

I'd just ***gotten used*** to my new keyboard after months of practice, then my sister ruined it by spilling coffee on it.

I just ***got used*** to my new keyboard after months of practice, then my sister ruined it by spilling coffee on it.

"They just changed the road sign on seventh did you see?"

"Sure ***you'll get used to*** it in a couple of weeks."

Comment: I would say _get to know_ and _get used to_ are idioms; _get to_ is not productive in that sense. There's another sense of "manage to", or "achieve", or "be able to" which is productive.